# withMaven UNSTABLE build result is not preserved in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to set a build's result to `UNSTABLE` when a maven build step exits because of test failures.
I'm using the withMaven build step which provides special treatment of maven test results:
In case of failing tests, it sets the build result to `UNSTABLE` before failing the step.

This works perfectly when using a scripted pipeline.
In case of a declarative pipeline, however, the build result is set to `FAILURE`.

This is illustrated by the following code samples.

*Edit: Please note that the the try/catch and post blocks are not required for the example to work. They are only present so that the value of `currentBuild.result` can be examined right after the invocation of `withMaven`.*

**Declarative**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                withMaven() {
                    sh 'mvn clean verify' // -> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
                }
            }

            post {
                always {
                    echo "CurrentResult: $currentBuild.currentResult" // -> FAILURE
                    echo "Result: $currentBuild.result"               // -> FAILURE
                                                                      // overall build result -> FAILURE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Scripted**

```
node() {
    stage('Build') {
        try {
            withMaven() {
                sh 'mvn clean verify'  // -> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
            }
        } catch (e) {
            echo "CurrentResult: $currentBuild.currentResult" // -> UNSTABLE
            echo "Result: $currentBuild.result"               // -> UNSTABLE
                                                              // overall build result -> UNSTABLE
        }
    }
}
```

How can i preserve the build result of `UNSTABLE` from a maven build step in a declarative pipeline?

Versions used: Jenkins 2.204.1, Pipeline Maven Integration Plugin 3.8.2, Maven 3.6.3 (installed on the build agent), AdoptOpenJDK 1.8.0_222.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As fredericrous pointed out, the difference is the caught exception.
If the exception is not caught in the Jenkinsfile, then the result will be set to *FAILED*.

I am not an expert, but i came up with a pure declarative approach which solve this problem in exchange of a more cluttered Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: null, catchInterruptions: false) {
                    withMaven() {
                        sh 'mvn clean verify' // -> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
                    }
                }
            }

            post {
                always {
                    echo "CurrentResult: $currentBuild.currentResult" // -> UNSTABLE
                    echo "Result: $currentBuild.result"               // -> UNSTABLE
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            when {
                expression {
                    currentBuild.result == "SUCCESS"
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Deploy'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Explanation

`catchError(buildResult: null, catchInterruptions: false)`

`buildResult: null` which is equivalent to `buildResult: 'SUCCESS'`, prevents `catchError` to set the buildResult to *FAILURE*, regardless of the value before.

`catchInterruptions: false` tells catchError to not catch, respectively rethrow, certain types of exceptions that are used to interrupt the flow of execution for Pipelines.

The "drawback" of catching the exception is that the current, and all following, `stages` are executed.
To skip a stage in regard of the result, a `when` declarative can be added to the stages.

This is how it looks from the stage view

[image: Stage View]

Comment: I see. In the context of a declarative pipeline, any uncaught exception causes the stage and thus the run to fail with a result of `FAILURE`, regardless of any previously set build result (e.g. `UNSTABLE` set by `withMaven`).

Comment: I like this approach. In my case, I have one specific pipeline that runs performance tests, and the tests are designed to fail when the performance goes below a certain factor. I wanted the pipeline to turn yellow when performance is bad, and red when there is an actual error for example when the underlying API has changed and the tests won't even run any more.

Comment: I just thought of another use case. I have another pipeline where I have stages Compile, Static Code Analysis (CheckStyle, PMD, SpotBugs,...), Tests (SureFire, FailSafe), Package, Deploy. Currently I have configured the static code analysis tools not to fail, which also means that nobody looks at them, but with this trick, I can make them fail, set the stage to Unstable, and still continue the build. It's our internal policy that code quality issues need to be resolved, but shouldn't break the build.

Answer (score 0):

the difference between your pipelines is that you used try/catch on the scripted one. What I would do is the following

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        withMaven() {
                            sh 'mvn clean verify' // -> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        echo "CurrentResult: $currentBuild.currentResult" // -> UNSTABLE
                        echo "Result: $currentBuild.result"               // -> UNSTABLE
                    }
                }
            }

            post {
                always {
                    echo "CurrentResult: $currentBuild.currentResult" // -> UNSTABLE
                    echo "Result: $currentBuild.result"               // -> UNSTABLE
                                                                      // overall build result -> UNSTABLE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try/catch won't help here. `withMaven` automatically distinguishes between a failing maven invocation due to build failures and one due to test failures and sets the build status accordingly to either `FAILURE` or `UNSTABLE`. Your suggestion aims at _always_ setting the result to `UNSTABLE`.

Comment: true, im no expert with the withMaven step? does my updated answer work? It looks weird to me that you used to use try catch and you droped it expecting the same results

Comment: Your solution is very helpful because it narrowed the problem scope to exception handling. I do not like the idea to insert a scripted pipeline block with conventional error handling inside a declarative pipeline, though. @Dennis Kronbügel found a solution at a level that is more "declarative", so I preferred his answer.

Comment: I like Dennis answer too. Personally I try too not to use too much the script block. When I need to script, I create a shared lib step